# Object-fit and image map css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with image inside it. Following is the CSS

```
img {
    width: 100%; /* or any custom size */
    height: 100%; 
    object-fit: contain;
}
body, html {
     height: 100%;
}
#mydiv {
    border:5px dashed #0000cc;
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; 
    margin:auto;
}
```

HTML is -

```
    <div id="mydiv" class="animated zoomIn">
            <img src="img/6.gif"/>
            <a href="test1.html" title="test" style="position: absolute; left: 22.98%; top: 14.85%; width: 20.58%; height: 15.15%; z-index: 2;"></a>
            <a href="test2.html" title="test2" style="position: absolute; left: 57.29%; top: 14.39%; width: 18.52%; height: 15.76%; z-index: 2;"></a>
            <a href="test3.html" title="test3" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 39.39%; width: 19.21%; height: 19.24%; z-index: 2;"></a>
            <a href="test4.html" title="test4" style="position: absolute; left: 79.76%; top: 40.76%; width: 19.73%; height: 15.45%; z-index: 2;"></a>
            <a href="test5.html" title="test5" style="position: absolute; left: 20.75%; top: 67.42%; width: 21.44%; height: 15.3%; z-index: 2;"></a>
            <a href="test6.html" title="test6" style="position: absolute; left: 58.66%; top: 67.27%; width: 16.98%; height: 15%; z-index: 2;"></a>
    </div>
```

The image clicks have been generated from [this](https://www.zaneray.com/responsive-image-map/) website

**Issue** : When the image is object-fit inside the div, as it should show as per screen width and height, the image maps (or so called) do not move. In short the image rectangle (the area where the image fits) still fills in div. My expectation was image would shrink its bounds (when I put border to image, it should be smaller than that of div) thus placing the image map correctly. Now the image map are placed all over the screen.

Any pointer how I can achieve true responsive image map (or a href) in images with object-fit of image?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your description of what is not working as expected. Would it be possible to include a screen capture or a working example that shows the problem? One thing to note: `object-fit: contain` will maintain the original aspect ratio of the image, so it will not necessarily fill the entire `div`. Because of that, I would not expect the links to appear in the correct locations since they are based on the size of the `div`.

Comment: An image map consists of an `<img>`,  and `<map>` tag, and one or more `<area>` tags nested within the `<map>` tag.

Comment: @JackA. - I will paste the solution temporarily onto some server by sometime

Comment: @JackA. http://dtechnologies.co.in/newweb/ This is the link

Answer (score 0):

You can use `object-fit: cover;` Hope it will solve your problem. Here's my solution.

```css
img {
    width: 100%; /* or any custom size */
    height: 70vw; 
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center center;
}
body, html {
     height: 100%;
}
#mydiv {
    border:5px dashed #0000cc;
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; 
    margin:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv" class="animated zoomIn">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/J67Ukc8.jpg"/>
            <a href="test1.html" title="test" style="position: absolute; left: 22.98%; top: 14.85%; width: 20.58%; height: 15.15%; z-index: 2;"></a>
            <a href="test2.html" title="test2" style="position: absolute; left: 57.29%; top: 14.39%; width: 18.52%; height: 15.76%; z-index: 2;"></a>
            <a href="test3.html" title="test3" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 39.39%; width: 19.21%; height: 19.24%; z-index: 2;"></a>
            <a href="test4.html" title="test4" style="position: absolute; left: 79.76%; top: 40.76%; width: 19.73%; height: 15.45%; z-index: 2;"></a>
            <a href="test5.html" title="test5" style="position: absolute; left: 20.75%; top: 67.42%; width: 21.44%; height: 15.3%; z-index: 2;"></a>
            <a href="test6.html" title="test6" style="position: absolute; left: 58.66%; top: 67.27%; width: 16.98%; height: 15%; z-index: 2;"></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: I tried your solution, however, the image then doesn't gets responsive.I need the image to be fully visible in all screens. In case of object-position and object-fit to cover, it shows image from center

Comment: @VijayKumar I just edited my solution. Check it. Is it OK?

Comment: No, its not yet, the image just gets dragged to bottom of screen (needs to scroll)

Comment: I will post the problem html,css and its related files onto a temporary server shortly

Comment: I made another edit. Now it have not to scroll. @VijayKumar But yet I didn't understand your requirements.

Comment: http://dtechnologies.co.in/newweb/   --- This is the link. Check the image getting moved to bottom of screen, the green boxes are expected to be clickable. These boxes needs to be on top of image on corresponding arrows